# Apple Push Notification Development Vs Distribution Profile

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I've implemented the push notification in my iPhone App. It's working fine with the development profile but when I deployed it on the App Store it's not working at all. I think it's  a problem of Distribution Profile. Please help me to configure the distribution profile and let me know the steps to do it.

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the provisioning profile you have to make sure that the appID has a distribution certificate associated with it. Then you need to create a distribution provisioning certificate. Note that this will be different for development, ad hoc and app store distribution.

You also need to change the certificate that your APNS server is using. Finally, make sure that in xcode, your app is using the correct certificates when building your project and target.